# STM32G030F6 starts program in Flash and after a while it ends up unintentionaly in System Memory

Tags: stm32, bootloader, flash-memory

My board have PA14-BOOT0 pin connected to SWDCLK and PA13 to SWDIO.

The BOOT0 pin is not pulled up/down.

According to documentation when nBOOT_SEL bit = 1 and nBOOT0 bit = 1 the BOOT0 pin is ignored and microcontroller boots up from Main Flash. This is the factory setup.

The Flash Option Bytes (address 0x1FFF7800) have default value of 0xDFFFE1AA which I have confirmed (nBOOT_SEL=1, nBOOT0=1).

Im running very basic code:

```
int main(void)
{
  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
 
  volatile int cnt = 0;

  while (1)
  {
      ++cnt;
  }
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIDiv = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

When I step the code or run to breakpoint at `++cnt` multiple times everything works fine.
But when I let the program run freely and pause after a second the Program Counter shows address 0x1FFFxxxx which is somewhere in System Memory (Bootloader) and debug fails at that point.

I have checked registers for Reset Reason, I have set breakpoints in any interrupt handler I have found in Startup file, I have checked the VTOR for proper addres but I didnt manage to catch the moment the processor jumps to System Memory.

If I pull down the BOOT0 pin with 100k resistor the program starts to work normally. I can run program freely then pause and I will be at the the position `++cnt` as I expect.

The question is WHY I need to pull down BOOT0 down even the documentation states clearly that BOOT0 pin is IGNORED when nBOOT_SEL bit = 1 and nBOOT0 bit = 1? What kind of sorcery ;) is going on here that my program jumps to System Memory in the middle of debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. In my circuit, the STM32G030F6 was powered by a battery. When this battery got low, the microcontroller would perform correctly while stepping through code in the debugger; however, when running freely it would randomly reset.

Replacing the battery fixed the problem for me.